# How do I give my player object each a playerID attribute and make them move based on different inputs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float speed = 80.0f; // Code for how fast the ball can move. Also it will be public so we can change it inside of Unity itself. 
    private Rigidbody rb; // Variable that applies itself to Ball 


    void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Code That enables our Player to move around. 
    void Movement()
    {

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }

     // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
      Movement ();
    }
```

Comment: i want to implement the code into the Start method.

Comment: If you explain what you are trying to make and explain it well, maybe someone can understand your question and help you out. What inputs?

Comment: the inputs would be the keyboard keys to make it move. i have two player objects but i each player to have different keys to make it move

Comment: ok. that makes sense now. there many other ways to do this without id or creating another class. update your question with code for player one and code for player 2 and i will try to provide a way to do this.

Comment: i've edited it now

Comment: Your code was bad but I fixed that. What key do you want to control your player 2?

Comment: like the standard a,s,w,d keys

Comment: If a,s,w,d keys control player 2, what keys should be controlling player 1?

Comment: up arrow, left arrow, down arrow, and right arrow

Comment: I dropped my answer. It would be good if you learn basic Unity before trying to make anything. Just follow a unity tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");` and `Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");` detects aswd and up,down,left and right arrows. You have to mess around the Unity Input settings to change those so if you use `Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");`  and `Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");` , Unity will move both players unless you change the keys defined in Unity. The solution is to use `Input.GetKey()` and provide the key name. Create two players and attach rigidbody to them. You can then drag player one to Player1RB and Player2 to Player2RB in the Editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 80.0f; // Code for how fast the ball can move. Also it will be public so we can change it inside of Unity itself. 
    public Rigidbody player1RB; //Player 1 Rigidbody
    public Rigidbody player2RB; //Player 2 Rigidbody


    //Player 1 Code with aswd keys
    void Player1Movement()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            player1RB.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            player1RB.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            player1RB.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            player1RB.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed);

        }
    }

    //Player 2 Code with arrow keys
    void Player2Movement()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            player2RB.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            player2RB.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            player2RB.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            player2RB.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed);

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Player1Movement();
        Player2Movement();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow that makessense now, thank you very much. i was trying to develop my own code and it worked for player 2 but player 1 couldnt move anymore :/ thank you though

Comment: glad i was able to help. you can accept it as the answer if your problem is solved. i...g...b..o good luck bro!

Comment: Is this on a 3d scale or 2d scale?

Comment: 3D but if you want it to be 2D, replace all Vector3 with Vector2. Then replace Rigidbody with Rigidbody2D.

Comment: When i move my players they go in the air instead of staying on the ground though

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D game? Do you intend for up key to move up or forward?

Comment: 3d game i want to move my ball throughout my maze and i want it to move forward and down to move down ,and etc

Comment: Then you have to change all the `Vector3.up * speed` to `Vector3.forward * speed`. Also change all the `Vector3.down * speed` to `Vector3.back`. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah it works now thank you very much you ave been so helpful!!

Comment: No problem. Just make sure that learn unity basic before asking another question. Your first question and the code you provided is a sign you need to learn the basic. There are many tutorials on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the `Input.GetKeyDown` function. You will need to supply this a keycode to make it work, however. This function returns a boolean so you can use this in an if statement. Here are the functions for your WASD keys. The keycodes look a little something like this.

```
Keycode.W
```

So for example your if statement would look like this `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)`.Then to move you would move the gameobject's transform in a given x y or z direction depending upon which button was pressed. If you want to you can multiply the value you want to move by the speed so that you can change the variable later. If you need code samples please ask. To make each player have a playerid you could include a variable in your script and in your start method you could generate a player id or a guid and fill that variable. You will want to make the variable public thought if you want to access the variable outside of that immediate script.

Comment: May i have a code sample, i undertand what you mean though