# Running Javascript code on Unity giving error.

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Hello everyone trying to built a simple game,

this is my code 
when i run this code its giving me the error 'playerMovement' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody'.

```
public var speed : int = 15;
var player : Rigidbody;
var player2 : Rigidbody;

function Start () {
player = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
player2 = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function playerMovement(){
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
    Debug.Log("Player 1 is moving forward");
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
}

}

function player2Movement(){
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
    Debug.Log("Player 2 is moving forward");
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
}

} 

function Update () {
player.playerMovement();
player2.playerMovement();
}
```

its giving me the error 'playerMovement' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody'. 
how to resolve this.

Comment: function Update () {
player.playerMovement();
player2.playerMovement();
}

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I see now it is bit more complecated so deleted it. So what you really want is to have two SEPARATE scripts fro player1 and player2. You tried somehow magicaly call playerMovement method from RigidBody reference.

Comment: Can't we make it in a single script and making two methods for each player and calling them in a Update method

Comment: Sure we can. But then the question remaning is what you really want - right now you would move two players objects in the smae time as they use same key codes two trigger movement. You need I quess some logic to separate triggering their movement.

Comment: yupp i have change my logic i hav eassigned separate keys to them. But still both are moving with the same keys...

Comment: @Sami Gave you answer in C# few days ago. Now, you want to convert the code to JavaScript. That's like converting your Ferrari into a bicycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pay attention when porting your code from [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37543938/3785314) to Javascript.

```
player.playerMovement();
player2.playerMovement();
```

The functions you are calling are both in the same script.

Just call them directly.

```
playerMovement();
player2Movement();
```

Also notice the bad spelling change in the code above player**2**Movement.

Even when you fixed that, it will compile with no error but won't work as expected because of:

```
player = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
player2 = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
```

Since you have different GameObject/balls to move. You have to use `GameObject.Find` to find them before getting the `Rigidbody` reference of each of them.

```
player = GameObject.Find("Ball1").GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
player2 =  GameObject.Find("Ball2").GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
```

Finally, the controls are messed up. You are using the-same control. I think this is a bad copy and paste or something but below is your whole working code.

**Note**:

Before you say it doesn't work, make sure that that your two GameObject/balls are named **Ball1** and **Ball2** and also make sure that the old C# cold is not attached to them. The code was tested and it works!

```
#pragma strict

public var speed : int = 15;
var player : Rigidbody;
var player2 : Rigidbody;

function Start () {
    player = GameObject.Find("Ball1").GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
    player2 =  GameObject.Find("Ball2").GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function playerMovement(){
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        player.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        player.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        player.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
        Debug.Log("Player 1 is moving forward");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        player.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed);
    }
}

function player2Movement(){
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        player2.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
        Debug.Log("Player 2 is moving forward");
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        player2.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        player2.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        player2.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
    }

} 

function Update () {
    playerMovement();
    player2Movement();
}
```

Comment: Worked !!!! Thanks loads... I have no idea abot the GameObject.Find method..Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

`playermovement` function isn't part of a `rigidbody` it is part of script that is attached to a `gameObject` 
so each  gameobject that wants to call this must have this script attached to them and you can  call their move function just by calling `playerMovement()` inside the script

```
public var speed : int = 15;
var player : Rigidbody;

function Start () {
player = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function playerMovement(){
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
    Debug.Log("Player 1 is moving forward");
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
}

}


function Update () {
 playerMovement();
}
```

and what you wrote got another problem and that is you are moving your both players with the same keys at the same times , so you have to make separate keys for each players input or make it turn based , it is up to your game

```
public var speed : int = 15;
var player1Obj: GameObject;
var player2Obj: GameObject;
var player : Rigidbody;
var player2 : Rigidbody;

function Start () {
player = player1Obj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
player2 = player2Obj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
}

function playerMovement(){
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
    Debug.Log("Player 1 is moving forward");
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
    player.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
}

}

function player2Movement(){
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.forward*speed);
    Debug.Log("Player 2 is moving forward");
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.back*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.left*speed);
}
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
    player2.AddForce(Vector3.right*speed);
}

} 

function Update () {
playerMovement();
player2Movement();
}
```

Comment: I have two game objects, and i have applied rigidbodies to both of the object. Now I am trying to assign separate keys for both of them so they can move. The problem i am facing is to identify how to link the game objects in my script. i write this player = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>(); for gameobject 1 and player2 = GetComponent.<Rigidbody>(); for gameobject 2 but its still not resolve.

Comment: milad, coincidently my code is similar to yours it stills moving both the player with the single key. I think the problem is in with start functions because we are assigning identical things to both player and player2

Comment: yes , I changed it ,  assign the two gameobjects player one and player two to , `player1obj` and `player2obj` via inspector